# Passing a variable to powershell on remote machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have an odd issue I've been working on here.  Basically I need to delete the profile folders on remote servers for users matching certain criteria.  I don't want to delete the actual user profile on the server (the registry keys are removed automatically, the profile folders are supposed to be but occasionally some get stuck) so the wmi class won't work, I just need to the delete the folders.

I've tried it thorough get-childitem | remove-item but there's always a permissions issue.  The only thing I know will work every time is rmdir /s /q which involves bringing up a command prompt.  I've tried this several ways but so far the closest I think I've come is below, where I'm getting hung up is trying to pass the $Directory variable to the command prompt.  I even delved into system variables at one point but that really wasn't working and I'd prefer to avoid it if at all possible.

```
    Function Profile-Cleanup {
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
    Enter-PSSession $Session

    Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
        cd c:\Users\
        $Directories = Get-ChildItem ("c:\Users") | Where-Object {(($_.Name -like "1*") -OR ($_.Name -like "2*") -OR ($_.Name -like "3*") -OR ($_.Name -like "*Temp*")) -and ($_.Name -notlike "a*") -and ($_.Name -notlike "b*") -and ($_.Name -notlike "C*")}
        ForEach($Directory in $Directories){

           Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "rmdir /q /s" $Directory.Name ,"Exit" -Wait -Verb RunAs -PassThru

        }

    }
    Exit-PSSession
    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession 
    }
```

Ok thank you @gms0ulman tying the full command to a variable was the trick I needed.  Thank you as well @postanote though I'm not using it in this script block yet I am going to pass the parameters through once I can work it out but for now this is my working code for anyone else having this trouble.

```
Function Profile-Cleanup {
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
$actiongood = $True
Try {
    Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
        cd c:\Users\
        $Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        $date = (get-date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
        $Directories = Get-ChildItem ("c:\Users") | Where-Object {(($_.Name -like "1*") -OR ($_.Name -like "2*") -OR ($_.Name -like "3*") -OR ($_.Name -like "*Temp*")) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $date) -and ($_.Name -notlike "a*") -and ($_.Name -notlike "b") -and ($_.Name -notlike "c")}
        ForEach($Directory in $Directories){            
        $process = "/c rmdir /q /s " + $Directory.Name
        Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList $process, "Exit" -Wait -Verb RunAs
        }
    } -ErrorAction Stop

}Catch {
    Write-Host "Unable to process Profile Cleanup on computer " $Computer " ...sorry" -ForegroundColor Red
    $actiongood = $False
}
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession    
If ($actiongood){
    $FailedDirectories = Get-ChildItem ("\\"+ $Computer + "\C$\Users") | Where-Object {(($_.Name -like "1*") -OR ($_.Name -like "2*") -OR ($_.Name -like "3*") -OR ($_.Name -like "*Temp*")) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $date) -and ($_.Name -notlike "a*") -and ($_.Name -notlike "n") -and ($_.Name -notlike "c")}
    Write-Host "The following are the user profiles were unable to be fully deleted on " $Computer " likely because they were in use" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host $FailedDirectories
    Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "Starting Next Process" -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor Black
    Write-Host "..." -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor Black
}
```

}

Comment: This has something to do with having to use strings or arrays to pass the variables - can't find source. Any luck if you use a variable to store the first part - `$v = "rmdir /q /s" + $Directory.Name` - then use later - `-ArgumentList  $v ,"Exit"`

Comment: Actually I think that may have done it...once I get full confirmation I'll post the updated code.

Comment: Nicely done. Consider posting the solution edit [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

As for your main goal.....

> Passing a variable to powershell on remote machine

... it really depends on what version of PoSH you are using. Later version allow the use of the following...

> USING REMOTE VARIABLES
>
> Windows PowerShell assumes that the variables used in remote commands
>   are defined in the session in which the command runs.
>
> In the following example, the $ps variable is defined in the temporary
>   session in which the Get-WinEvent command runs.
>
> Invoke-Command -ComputerName S1 -ScriptBlock {$ps = "Windows
>   PowerShell"; Get-WinEvent -LogName $ps}
>
> Similarly, when the command runs in a persistent session (PSSession),
>   the remote variable must be defined in the same PSSession.
>
> USING LOCAL VARIABLES
>
> You can also use local variables in remote commands, but you must
>   indicate that  the variable is defined in the local session.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope
>   modifier to  identify a local variable in a remote command.
>
> The syntax of Using is as follows:
>
> The syntax is: $Using:
>
> In the following example, the $ps variable is created in the local
>   session, but  is used in the session in which the command runs. The
>   Using scope modifier  identifies $ps as a local variable.
>
> USING LOCAL VARIABLES IN WINDOWS POWERSHELL 2.0
>
> You can use local variables in a remote command by defining parameters
>   for the  remote command and using the ArgumentList parameter of the
>   Invoke-Command  cmdlet to specify the local variable as the parameter
>   value.
>
> This command format is valid on Windows PowerShell 2.0 and later
>   versions of  Windows PowerShell.
>
> -- Use the param keyword to define parameters for the remote command. The  parameter names are placeholders that do not need to match the
>   name of the  local variable.
>
> -- Use the parameters defined by the param keyword in the command.
>
> -- Use the ArgumentList parameter of the Invoke-Command cmdlet to specify the  local variable as the parameter value.
>
> For example, the following commands define the $ps variable in the
>   local  session and then use it in a remote command. The command uses
>   $log as the  parameter name and the local variable, $ps, as its value.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Well that helps get me a step closer I think.  The problem is not just passing the variable to a remote session, that's not necessarily required since in the code I posted I'm getting the variable $Directory" inside the Invoke-Command block.  The trouble I'm having is passing the variable to the Start-Process cmd, the command prompt never picks up the variable.